# Rspec Instance Double Received Unexpected Message

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing rspec tests for my `#check?` method within my chess game but hitting an error with the `start_coordinates` variable stored in my `Board` class, which in rspec is an instance double.

Unsure how to allow my `#check?` method to change `start_coordinates` in rspec when it runs.

```
  def check?(king_coordinates)
    check = nil
    @chess.board.each do |array|
      array.each do |square|
        next if square == '' || square.which_player != whos_turn

        if square.which_player == whos_turn
          row = @chess.board.detect{ |aa| aa.include?(square) }
          @chess.start_coordinates = [row.index(square) + 1, 8 - @chess.board.index(row)]
          check = square.valid_move?(@chess, square.which_player) ? true : false
        else
          false
        end
      end
    end
    check
  end
```

My rspec looks like this:

```
  describe '#check?' do
    subject(:game_check) { described_class.new(player_one, player_two, board_class)}

    let(:board_class) { instance_double(Board, board: [
      ['', '', rook, '', '', '', king, ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', bishop, '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    ], start_coordinates: nil, finish_coordinates: nil) }
  
    before do
      allow(game_check).to receive(:whos_turn).and_return(player_one)
      ## allow(board_class).to receive(:start_coordinates).and_return([3, 8]) ## Tried this 
    end

    it 'returns true' do
      expect(game_check.check?([7, 8])).to eq(true)
    end
  end
```

My error message is:

```
  #<InstanceDouble(Board) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :start_coordinates= with ([3, 8])
```

I have tried shown in the code above:

```
  allow(board_class).to receive(:start_coordinates).and_return([3, 8])
```

**Update to show `Board` class:**

```
lass Board
  attr_reader :board, :start_coordinates, :start_square, :finish_coordinates, :finish_square

  def initialize(player1, player2)
    @player1 = player1
    @player2 = player2

    @start_square = nil
    @finish_square = nil
    @start_coordinates = []
    @finish_coordinates = []

    @board = [
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
    ]
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the "setter" method `start_coordinates=` but you are only "allowing" the "getter" method `start_coordinates`.

Instead try changing

```
 allow(board_class).to receive(:start_coordinates).and_return([3, 8])
```

To

```
allow(board_class).to receive(:start_coordinates=)
```

That being said a setter (method ending in `=`) will always return the argument passed in so `and_return` is not useful here but you could use `with()` if you want to be explicit about the arguments `:start_coordinates=` are expected to receive

Example:

```
def hello=(n)
'Hi'
end 

hello= 12
#=> 12
```

Comment: thanks - tried this but get this error: `the Board class does not implement the instance method: start_coordinates=`

Comment: @Christian assuming `@chess` is an instance of `Board` you are calling `start_coordinates=` on line 8 of the `check?` method in your question. You have not provided any additional details for the `Board` class so it will be very difficult to help here.

Comment: Correct `@chess` is an instance of `Board`.  The `check?` method lives inside the `Game` class so I am calling `@chess.start_coordinates` from within the `Game` class

Comment: @Christian you are calling `start_coordinates=` are you sure `Board` has this method?

Comment: yes it does please see my question update

Comment: @Christian `attr_reader` only defines `start_coordinates` (the getter) but in your `check?` method you are calling `start_coordinates=` (the setter). Either add `attr_accessor :start_coordinates` or change the way your `check?` method works.

Comment: of course thank you - I will give this a shot!

Comment: I tried the above `attr_accessor` & `allow(board_class).to receive(:start_coordinates=)` but it still does not seem to changing `start_coordinates` when I have examined it with `binding.pry`.

Comment: I have the test passing but it seems a bit of a fudge due to `start_coordinates` not changing. I did this by changing making sure the `valid_move?` always returns true for both the `bishop` and `rook`.